# Automated subscription service using PayPal or other payment processor?

Tags: paypal, payment, subscription, payment-processing, paypal-subscriptions

I am developing an app which will be free to download from the Apple App store. However, users will be able to subscribe for advanced features which include the use of a web service. I would like the ability to detect those users who have subscribed and then cancelled their subscriptions so I can halt the use of the web service. I would like to do this automatically.

I know PayPal is one way to set up subscriptions, but is it able to detect when people cancel their subscriptions and notify me in a way that my web service can be automatically updated?

Any other advice or pointers welcomed - I cant be the first person/company looking to do this. But I dont really know where to start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need two specific features: recurring billing and webhooks. The recurring billing will take care of the subscription, while the webhooks will automatically alert you to a cancellation so that your web service can be updated. Webhooks are real time notifications that alert you whenever an automated event occurs in our system. Payment gateways like Braintree offer both of these features.